# I am trouble to understand what is returning from the function when using the ES6 script. I am new to ES6, react and redux world

Tags: redux, ecmascript-6

I am new to react and redux trying to understand below code:

```
const initialState = { list: [] };

export default function (state = initialState , action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TICKET:
            return {
               ...state, 
               list: [...list, action.payload.data]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

What is the return statement doing here? Is it returning the two arrays i.e state and list?

Comment: It merges the new state (containing `list`) with the old state (`state`; the 3 dots mean to "expand" (spread) the old object into the new one, don't just create a single property) into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reducer updates state, it should not modify the **existing** state object in-place. Instead, it should generate a **new** object containing the necessary changes.

The case for handling the `GET_TICKET` action will add a new list item to the `state.list` and return a shallow copy(by es6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) instead of mutating the `state.list` in place.

From the doc [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns):

> The key to updating nested data is that every level of nesting must be copied and updated appropriately.

Also, see [Inserting and Removing Items in Arrays](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays)

Comment: slideshowp2 when you refers "The case for handling the GET_TICKET action will add a new list item to the state.list and return a shallow copy(by es6 spread operator) instead of mutating the state.list in place." Do you mean the return {... state, list: [...list, action.payload.data]} is returning the new list item to the state.list object with the new value i.e. action.payload.data

Comment: @Sabbu Yes, `state.list` is a shallow copy with a new list item `action.payload.data`